# Overide django admin ListFilter templates

Tags: django, django-admin, django-admin-filters, cookiecutter-django

I want to overide default django admin filter template to use my own template based on this:

> https://github.com/feincms/feincms/blob/master/feincms/templates/admin/filter.html

I've written my own `SimpleListFilter`class by inheriting from `django.contrib.admin.SimpleListFilter`

```
class PublisherStateFilter(admin.SimpleListFilter):
    title = _('Status')
    parameter_name = 'status'
    template = 'admin/blogitty/filter.html'

    [...]
```

This works perfectly.

[image: Dropdown Select Filter]

However I would like to use the same template for all admin filters. Is there a way to overide all filter templates for a given app, without having to define custom `ListFilter`for each `ForeignKey` and `ManyToMany` relationships.

With my project as `blogitty`. I tried both options for template DIR:

```
blogitty/templates/admin/filter.html
```

And:

```
blogitty/templates/admin/blogitty/filter.html
```

No luck :-(

Looking through the source code:

> https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L1030

```
    return TemplateResponse(request, form_template or [
        "admin/%s/%s/change_form.html" % (app_label, opts.model_name),
        "admin/%s/change_form.html" % app_label,
        "admin/change_form.html"
    ], context)
```

> https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L1569

```
    return TemplateResponse(request, self.change_list_template or [
        'admin/%s/%s/change_list.html' % (app_label, opts.model_name),
        'admin/%s/change_list.html' % app_label,
        'admin/change_list.html'
    ], context)
```

As far as I understand it. Django ModelAdmin checks multiple paths for rendering changeform or changelist for a given model. However for a `ListFilter`, no extra checks are done to load custom templates.

> https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/filters.py#L60

```
class ListFilter(object):
    title = None  
    template = 'admin/filter.html'
```

Update — TEMPLATE_DIRS settings:

```
BASE_DIR = dirname(dirname(__file__))    

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
)
```

Project layout is based on [cookiecutter-django](https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django) by Daniel Greenfeld

Answer (score 2):

This might help

```
class ClassFilter1(admin.ModelAdmin):
    title = 'Filter Class'
    parameter_name = 'filter-class'

    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
       # Your Lookups

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
       # Your Lookups

class FilterClass(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = (ClassFilter1, ClassFilter2)
    change_list_template = 'polls/change_list_template.html'
```

And overide the `change_list_template.html` and place the .html in `polls/templates/polls`